# Удаление дополнительных форм

Tags: javascript

Сами формы добавляю таким образом

```
<script>
function append(id) {
    var node = document.getElementById(id),
        newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="name[]" value="" />';
    node.appendChild(newNode);
    return newNode;
}  
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
<a href="" onclick="append('test'); return false;">CLICK</a>
```

А как сделать удаление определенной формы? Что-то не соображу.

Comment: Решил данную проблемку.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var idme = 0;
function del_image(i) 
{
  var newit = document.getElementById('item_'+i).parentNode.parentNode;
  newNode = newit.parentNode.removeChild(newit);
  return newNode;
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="del_image('+idme+'); return false;" title="Удалить"><img src="{$home}/style/{$setup.skin}/images/del_ico.png" alt="del"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Comment: Если сделать test.parentNode.removeChild(test); то удалятся все формы.